# Disable the Google Plus red notification number on Gmail, Google search, etc

Tags: google-plus, google-chrome, notifications, firefox

How can I disable the big red number showing on the Google account bar that comes from Google+ activity?

Whenever there are new notifications from Google+ the box turns red showing a number or count of how many messages/updates are waiting.

I want to disable this. I use mainly Google Chrome and Firefox if an extension or add-on is the way to block this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with just some CSS:

http://userstyles.org/styles/50447/hide-google-notifications

Comment: As of today, this one works. Thanks for making me discover stylish!

Comment: it's currently deleted

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a new userstyle for the latest (March, 2012) version of Google and Gmail's sharing bar.

If you use a localized Google domain, like google.de, you will need to add it to the script.

http://userstyles.org/styles/63098/hide-google-plus-notifications-march-2012?r=1332718041

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Chrome plugin called Google+ Notifications Remover](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google%2B-notifications-rem/aikimbhjhcccpkokpbmfpagjdocdcodo/related).
From my first impressions, it works quite well. The bell momentarily appears and then disappears from all the sites I would want it to disappear (google.com, google.com.au, image search, youtube). It would be better if the bell never appeared. The bell does appear in Google+ where you would presumably want it.

Also, if you use Chrome and are seeing the notification in your [new tab page, here are a few workarounds](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/62776846051/removing-google-chromes-google-notifier-from-home).

Answer (score 0):

1. with Firefox [Addon Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=ss) you can use http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/106622
2. with Firefox [Addon Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) there is http://userstyles.org/styles/50890/google-plus-notification-hide
3. Google describes [here](https://support.google.com/toolbar/answer/1692564?hl=en) that you can easily switch notifications off, however, I could not find it...
4. don't use Google ;)

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score -2):

In that top bar where it has the red number, all the way on the right will be a gear. click it, then go to google+ settings. Under google+ notifications, uncheck them all (the boxes).

Comment: That's for email notifications only